# What is the difference using split pattern with slashes // or quotes ''|""?

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

Sometimes I get bitten from really basic things. I recalled having different `split` behavior based on using `PATTERN` as a string or a regex. Now reading [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) seems there is no such distinction, in whole docs there is just one case (`awk`-like behavor) where the pattern is presented as quoted string, in every other example the pattern is between slashes, as a regex. Still, I found examples/tutorials [here](http://www.perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html) and [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-split-function/), for example, where is mentioned distinction of character, string and pattern based split. Still, in tests I did not found more differences besides when splitting on the slash is nicer to use quotes (`split '/', $some_string`).

My specific problem today was splitting filenames on dot `.` and expecting to split on string-pattern. For my surprise the pattern `'.'` was still treated as regex, so the following script fails for this purpose:

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

my ( @x ) = split '.', 'dir/some_file.ext';
say "@x";
```

I know, how to fix my script (using regex pattern), but  I still don't know, what is the difference using the pattern as string (`'.'`) versus regex (`/./`)?

Comment: Tip: Paths often contain more than one `.`, and they often contain a `.` that doesn't indicate the start of an extension. `split` is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Please see [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html),[perlreref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) and look for **delimiter**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in most cases `split /PATTERN/, $str` and `split "PATTERN", $str` do the same thing. In the string version, the string is usually treated as a regular expression

The pages you linked fail to mention on their examples that if the separator contains any regex-special characters, they must be escaped, even using the string syntax. For example,

```
@parts = split '|', $str;  # Oops, gives a list of single chars including |
@parts = split '\|', $str; # Separates on | character
```

If the separator is a variable which might contain regex-special characters, you would need the `quotemeta` function, possibly by putting a `\Q` in an interpolation.

```
@parts = split quotemeta($sep), $str;
@parts = split "\Q$sep", $str;        # Same thing
```

Of course the single quotes `'TEXT'` and the double quotes `"TEXT"` have lots of differences, but that's not directly related to the `split` function.

The actual differences between `split /PATTERN/, $str` and `split "PATTERN", $str` are:

- There are different rules about escaping characters in a `//` syntax and a `""` syntax.
- With `/PATTERN/` it's possible to add the regex modifier flags. Like `split /\bend$/mi, $str` splits on the word "end" ignoring case when it appears at the end of a line. (With a string, you would need a syntax like `"(?mi:\\bend\$)"`.)
- An expression which evaluates equal to the string `" "` has special behavior, ignoring initial whitespace and splitting on runs of whitespace. Using `/ /` doesn't use that special case, and just splits on each single space character.

Answer (score 5):

No matter what syntax you use, `split'`s first operand must evaluate to a regex pattern.<sup>[1]</sup>

As such, `split '.'` and `split /./` both split on the regex pattern `.`, meaning that the strings to return are separated by any character but a newline.

Do note that single-quoted string literals (`'...'`, `q'...'`, `q!...!`, `q{...}`, etc), double-quoted string literals (`"..."`, `qq"..."`, `qq!...!`, `qq{...}`, etc), and regex literals (`qr/.../`, `/.../`, `m/.../`, `s/...//`, etc) have different parsing rules. For example `split "\+"` and `split /\+/` will have different effects, but only because `"\+"` is the just a weird way of writing `"+"`.

I recommend *always* using a match operator (e.g. `/.../`) or a `qr` operator (e.g. `qr/.../`) over a string literal (except for `' '`, of course). These are best suited to construct a regex pattern, and these signal to your reader that you are producing a regex pattern.

---

1. Two exceptions:

   - A match operator is treated as a regex-string literal. For example, `/.../` is treated as `qr/.../`.
   - An expression that evaluates to a string that consists of a single space (`' '` and `" "`, but not `/ /` or `qr/ /`) means that the strings to return are separated by whitespace and that leading whitespace should be ignored.

Comment: I also make an exception when the delimiter is `/`. `split '/',...` looks better than `split /\//,...` or `split m!/!,...`

Comment: @mob, I meant always use a `m` or `qr` operator; I didn't mean to always use `/` as the delimiter. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code splits full path into it's components. It uses delimiter `!` in regex to avoid escaping `/` as it is default regex **delimiter** -- it makes the code easier to read (understand)

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my %parts;

my $path = '/home/user/docs/file.ext';

my @components = qw(path name ext);

@parts{@components} = ( $path =~ m!(.*?)/(\w+)\.(\w+)! );

say Dumper(\%parts);
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'path' => '/home/user/docs',
          'ext' => 'ext',
          'name' => 'file'
        };
```

Please visit [perlrequick](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) and look for **delimiter**.

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad, so I must clarify: extracting path etc is not the point of my question.

Comment: I do understand that extracting path is not `core` of the question -- it is just a sample how it should be done. Otherwise a programmer is free to choose **delimiter** as he/she fills best fit to maintain/read code -- for example `/` requires escaping with default regex `/` **delimiter**. Special case is for `.` as it is a **metacharacter** in regex meaning _any character_. [Metacharacters](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters) require special treatment in regex -- if it is part of _search pattern_ then they should be escaped.

Comment: Let's say this way: I still can't see relation to my question ;)

Comment: Your question is about [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) which uses [pattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#The-Basics) and particularly `'.'`. **Pattern** by definition is **regex** which can be specified with various **delimiters** `//,!!,||,<>,{},'',##` -- type of **delimiter** is a convenience to the programmer to make the code easier to understand. To put it other way there is no difference between `'.'` and '/./' -- both mean any character, if intended literal `.` then it should be `'\.'` or '/\./'. Now it is upto programmer to chose which one he prefers.

Comment: In case of **split** commonly used two delimiters `/` and `'` which interchangeable. Delimiter `'` is more convenient to use for strings which include `/` to avoid escaping `/` symbol -- `my $path = '/home/user/dir/file.ext'`. Delimiter `/` is more convenient to use for strings which include `'` -- `my $str = "'home'user'dir'file.ext'"`.

Comment: My question is about 2 different use of `split` PATTERN-part, because: a) documentation does not state difference of using string literal and regex literal  b) I don't know any other context in Perl, where string literal is treated as regex.

Comment: Following web page [demonstrates](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-split-function/) usage of split function with different type patterns and commentaries.

Comment: Yes, my question links to the same page ;)

Comment: Following code is completely valid `my $path = "1home2user3docs4file.ext5"; my @a = split '\d+', $path;` -- no difference from `my @a = split /\d+/, $path;`. Perhaps this specific applies only to **split** function.